# $(document).ready() & $(function(){}

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions:

```
function func1(){}
```

and

```
function func2(){}
```

both of these functions requires the following to work

```
$(document).ready();
$(window).resize();
```

so I have implemented it to both the functions as follows:

```
$(document).ready(func1);
$(window).resize(func1);
```

and

```
$(document).ready(func2);
$(window).resize(func2);
```

**The problem? there is two;**

**1)** I already have `$(function(){` wrapping the above two functions, but I still need need `$(document).ready();` why? isn't both the same thing?!

**2)** I am trying to short-cut the code and only have `$(document).ready();`"if needed" and `$(window).resize();` to appear once and then add functions to it, and not add it to functions. Confused? okay...

so I basically want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(func1,func2);
$(window).resize(func1,func2);
```

But it didn't work, any ideas?

My script:

```
$(function(){

   //Prevent clicking on .active & disabled links
   'use strict'; $('.active, disabled').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });

   //Off-canvas menu
   var $pages = $('#page, #secondHeader'),
       $header = $('#header'),
       $secondHeader = $('#secondHeader .menu-button');

   $secondHeader.on('touchstart click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $pages.toggleClass("pageOpen");
      $header.toggleClass("headerOpen");
      $(this).toggleClass("menu-button-active");
   });

   $('#page').on('touchstart click', function() {
      $pages.removeClass("pageOpen");
      $header.removeClass('headerOpen');
      $secondHeader.removeClass("menu-button-active");
   });

   //Grid system
   var gridElement = $(".gridElement", "#grid3");
   (function() {
      $(document).ready(GalleryGrid);
      $(window).resize(GalleryGrid);
   })(jQuery);

   function GalleryGrid() {
      var grid3 = $('#grid3');
      var width = $(window).width();
      if (width < 1024 && width > 770) {
         var grid1 = $('#grid1');
         var grid2 = $('#grid2');

         for (var i = 0; i < gridElement.length; i++) {
            if (i < gridElement.length / 2) {
               grid1.append(gridElement[i]);
            } else {
               grid2.append(gridElement[i]);
            }
         }
      } else {
         grid3.append(gridElement);
      }
   }


   $(document).ready(fullScreen);
   $(window).resize(fullScreen);
   function fullScreen() {
       var newHeight = $("html").height() - $("#header").height() + "px";
       $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
   }

});
```

Comment: Check at the related [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Both of the functions that has $(document).ready() won't work without it, that is why I asked question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper function to call both functions on the same event:

```
function go(){
    func1(); // Call function 1 and 2.
    func2();
}

$(document).ready(go);
$(window).resize(go);
```

Or, to make absolutely sure the document is ready, you can even attach the `resize` event listener after the ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(go);
});
```

Comment: That is a good way to do it! however, why do I still need $(document).ready? if I already have $(function());

Comment: @Loai: Technically, no, but I'd still use it myself, as it's something every JavaScript programmer can recognize, making the code easier to maintain.

Comment: So I replace $(function(){ with $(document).ready(function(){ right mate?

Comment: @Loai or don't replace it. Just don't wrap ready handler inside an other ready handler, it is useless

Comment: Yea, but that wouldn't make a difference. However, you can remove the `$(document).ready(fullScreen);` line. Instead, you can just call `fullscreen()` at the end of your code (inside the `doc.ready`)

Comment: The problem is guys, the functions won't work without $(document).ready even that there is a $(function()); that what is confusing me!

Comment: @Loai so you debug it wrongly or provide any jsfiddle wich replicates your issue. Of course, ready handlers are processed in order you bind it, using a promise, maybe that's your issue

Comment: @Loai but you should remove all this nested ready handlers and btw the anonymous wrapper function. Put all these function calls at end of your `$(function(){}` code

Comment: Just updated the Fildde, please check "and update it if needed", I am having a problem with the GridGallery ones tho

Comment: If I removed "(function() {
      $(document).ready(GalleryGrid);
      $(window).resize(GalleryGrid);
   })(jQuery);" it won't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
 function fullScreen() {
      var newHeight = $("html").height() - $("#header").height() + "px";
      $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
    }
    fullScreen();
   GalleryGrid();
   $(window).resize(function(){
        fullScreen();
        GalleryGrid();
    });
```

Just call the function like `fullScreen()` no need to use $(document).ready.

For Gallery Grid

Remove from you code. No need to call (function(){}) twice.

```
(function() {
      $(document).ready(GalleryGrid);
      $(window).resize(GalleryGrid);
   })(jQuery);
```

Comment: your want to call 'GalleryGrid' function on both ready and resize ?

Comment: "no need to use $(document).ready" well, it depends where is set code

Comment: @RakeshKumar yes. But as you can see the GalleryGrid is just a missed-up code! I can't seem to be able to clean it up

Comment: @A.Wolff you missed understand me, is $(document).ready same as $(function(){?

Comment: @Loai yes it is exact same behaviour and ya i understood you, my comment wasn't relative to that

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an anonymous function to get this done.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    1();
    2();
});
```

That should be a good starting point.

Comment: As you can see I already have $(function(){ which is the same as $(document).ready(function() { wrapping all the functions. that what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

**(function(){ ... })();**

It is not equivalent to document.ready. Here it is not necessary DOM is ready. It is anonymous function it invoke itself as soon as possible when the browser is interpreting your ecma-/javascript.

Better and suggested to use document.ready():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fullScreen();

//other code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't

Don't call `$(document).ready()` inside `$(document).ready()`, it doesn't make sense. The code inside of `$(document).ready(/* the code here */)` is not executed immediately. It is scheduled for execution sometime later (when the document is ready).

Calling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do this
    $(document).ready(some_function)
    //do that
});
```

Is like saying "wait until the document is ready, do this, wait until the document is ready to do some_function, do that."

## Document `ready` event:

```
$(function(){})
```

Is just a shortcut/shorthand for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

`ready` is an event. It belongs to the `document` object and it is triggered when the document is ready.

To register two functions to be called when the document is ready just do either:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    func1();
    func2();
});
```

Or

```
$(function() {
    func1();
    func2();
});
```

Or

```
function func3() {
    func1();
    func2();
}
$(document).ready(func3);
```

Or

```
function func3() {
    func1();
    func2();
}
$(func3);
```

## Window `resize` event:

`resize` is an event. It belongs to the `window` object and it is triggered when the window is resized.

To register two functions to be called when the window is resized just do:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    func1();
    func2();
});
```

Or

```
function func3() {
    func1();
    func2();
}
$(window).resize(func3);
```

Comment: There is such a thing as over-explaining something ;)

Comment: @Cerbrus -- I am working under the assumption that OP is more or less copy-pasting code without the faintest idea of what the event-driven model of JavaScript is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @Cerbrus also listing every possible combination of the shorthand/longhand syntax is my OCD kicking in.

Comment: Hm, the first point is a valid one, yes. My comment was more about the second point. Nothing serious, though :-)